# Trigger for re-setting auto-increment of tables in phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin, record

I have a database, tvguide and these are the values:

```
id bigint 255 UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
programme varchar 255 
default value (which is from another table
with list of programs, the only linked field that
is shared with other table):<b><a href="gossipgirl.php">Gossip Girl</a></b>
channel varchar 255
airdate DATETIME - actual airtime
displayair DATETIME (rounded-up datetime, e.g. programme that airs 1.59pm 
would be shown as 2.00pm, or 6.08pm as 6.10pm)
expiration DATETIME - when program finishes
episode VARCHAR 255 NULL - has null option if episode unknown
series VARCHAR 255
epno VARCHAR 255 - episode number
setreminder VARCHAR255 (shows "set reminder", sends email to user, but that's 
another thing to work on).
```

I want to insert a trigger into my database so that if a record is deleted, the ID auto-increment re-sets itself automatically?

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I've done it manually so far but am looking at seeing what I can do with phpMyadmin when I delete the record.

BTW I made a copy of the table for backup purposes.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to reset auto increment, just let it growth ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with whitstone86's comment that you can just "let it grow".

Having said that, to change the `AUTO_INCREMENT` at any time, you can just run an `ALTER TABLE`.

Some pseudo code...

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS max_id_plus_one FROM my_table;

ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = $max_id_plus_one;
```

For production, race conditions might be an issue. However, if it's just you puttering around in phpmyadmin, this should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather dangerous idea.

Let it grow, it doesn't take place: 250000000011 use the same place as 250000000012 in your 
table, especially since it's a bigint (8 bytes).

Otherwise

- how do you know than Id=25 from 6 months ago is today Id=25 ?
- how do you maintain integrity constraints ? you must make sure than you have foreign keys everywhere with on update|delete cascade
- if you don't always delete the last record in the table, there is 0 gain since the next added record Id with at least be +1 of the previously added one.